# Stubbed class is still functioning like normally called

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a Class which I am testing and it has a method from another class which I am trying to stub so that it skips what it does and returns a fake object

```
class Service{
CacheClass cache;
CacheFactory factory;

public String getString(){
cache = factory.create();

...}
```

The factory create connects to a database and I want to skip this step; My test looks like this

```
@Before
public void setup(){
cache = mock(CacheClass.class);
factory = mock(CacheFactory.class);
when(factory.create()).thenReturn(cache);
}

@Test
public void testGetString(){
service = new Service();
String s = service.getString();
...}
```

When I try to run this test. It attempts to connect to the DB but I do not want it to.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the posted code, where do you think there's something to tell your "service" to use the mocks? You **have to** somehow "inject" you mocks into the service (using setters maybe)

Comment: That makes so much sense. I was expecting it to know to use my mocked factory just cos it was there. I created a setter and it works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Great, consider adding a "self-answer" and accepting it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
service = new Service();
```

this doesn't magically *inject* your mocked objects into that instance of Service.

You probably need something like:

```
service = new Service(mockedCache, mockedFactory);
```

There is also this annotation:

```
@InjectMocks
Service service;
```

that you could use to have mockito do that automatically; but unfortunately, this construct doesn't give you an error when injecting fails. Thus, simple do something like:

```
Servce underTest;

@Before
public void setup() {
  underTest = new Service(....
```